# Compare values in an array with the id of my data in the database and display in a datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, datagrid

I'm new in C# and I have an array with different values as shown below

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

I need to do is to relate the value of the array with the id of a data in my database in Sqlserver, Example, the first value for my array is 1, and the value from my data Id is  also 1, I need show in a DataGrid the the name or information that this id holds.

**DataBase Example:**

- id 1 , name Francisco, serial_number 1234
- id 2 , name Claudio, serial_number 4321

Comment: Not enough information. How is the array related to your DB? I'd like to see that in code.

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/119477) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/337864/119477)

Comment: im not implement yet, but i thing is compare the number 1 from the array with the id from data in Database

Comment: Why down vote if one is interested in learning?

Comment: yes, how match data id with value

Comment: @sneakthief only i wants is match that up with the value in my array

Comment: @ItiTyagi You might want to read [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/148672). The community generally removes them as opposed to adding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Query the database according to the values stored in your array.

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
string sql = "";

foreach (int id in array)
{
   // append your ids to variable sql seperated by commas
}
```

now your query should be for example :

```
"Select * from Table1 WHERE ID in (" + sql + ")"
```

PS: Don't accept user input for this query as it would be a potential SQL injection :-)

Comment: My answer is based on the array he declared in the OP

Comment: my array is only int vlaues know , is from a proyect with i need show datas from database with the array with random numbers